# NSTableView + NSProgressIndicator flickering issues

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsprogressindicator

I have a NSTableView which contains two columns, a NSTextField and a NSProgressIndicator object on each row. When I scroll up or down the NSProgressIndicator objects flicker, the same occurs when I select the text contained in the NSTextField. Does anyone know why?

This is the code I am using for creating the NSProgressIndicator objects in the 'viewForTableColumn' method:

```
... 
if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"Progress"]) {
   NSProgressIndicator* progressIndicator = (NSProgressIndicator*)cellView.nextKeyView;
   NSString *stringPercentage  = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Percentage"];
   [[progressIndicator animator] setDoubleValue:[stringPercentage doubleValue]];
}
...
```

Note: NSTextField's are only selectable (not editable).

Comment: Same issue here... Did you find any solution?

Comment: @NSAddict I found the way to fix this by adding [code]([progressIndicator setUsesThreadedAnimation:NO];) Let me know if it worked for you :)

Comment: I actually wrote my own version of `NSProgressIndicator`. It has many advantages, and it doesn't flicker ;)

https://github.com/iluuu1994/ITProgressIndicator

Comment: btw. you should add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could fix this by using: 
`[progressIndicator setUsesThreadedAnimation:NO];`

So that the final code is:

```
... 
if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"Progress"]) {
   NSProgressIndicator* progressIndicator = (NSProgressIndicator*)cellView.nextKeyView;
   NSString *stringPercentage  = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Percentage"];
   [[progressIndicator animator] setDoubleValue:[stringPercentage doubleValue]];
   [progressIndicator setUsesThreadedAnimation:NO];
}
...
```